# what is the best way using SQL to filter out file name with bracket and letter A or B inside of it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, filtering, sql-like, not-exists

```
Select filename

from cleansedreports s with (nolock)
where not exists (select 1
                  from (values ('D2'), ('P2')) v(Filename)
                  where s.Filename like '%' + v.Filename + '%')
```

So the above query basically filters out all the file name with D2 or P2 in it, is there way to filter out any D or P in it(like filanmes like D5, F27). The one common denominoar with all those file names are they have bracket inside it, like augustsalesreport[D21], Julysalesreport[P23].

What would best the best way filter out all files with bracket with letter D or P inside it?

Comment: can you tell us which databse you are using, or is it a secret. Besides you select from a table

Comment: sorry, see updated

Comment: you would use regular exprsiions for that, but i can't still tell which rdms system you are using

Comment: Can you please write an answer? I'm using sql studio

Comment: Microsoft sql studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression

> ```
> CREATE TABLE cleansedreports (filename varchar(30));
>   
> INSERT INTO cleansedreports VALUES  ('augustsalesreport[D21]'),('Julysalesreport[P23]'),('Julysalesreport[F23]')
> GO
> ```

3 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM cleansedreports WHERE filename LIKE '%[[][D|P][0-9]%]'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | filename               |
> | :--------------------- |
> | augustsalesreport[D21] |
> | Julysalesreport[P23]   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a3bc197eacbcb76d46e64679822b939)*